# Flutter error on Fedora - Downloaded executables cannot execute on host

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, fedora, libstdc++

Fedora 29.
Installed Flutter and Android Studio.
Executing `flutter doctor [-v]`
Output:

```
✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
  On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
  On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686
  On Arch: pacman -S lib32-libstdc++5
```

Executing `sudo dnf install libstdc++.i686`
Output:

```
Error: Transaction check error:
file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/printers.cpython-37.opt-1.pyc from install of libstdc++-8.2.1-5.fc29.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.2.1-4.fc29.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/__pycache__/printers.cpython-37.pyc from install of libstdc++-8.2.1-5.fc29.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.2.1-4.fc29.x86_64
file /usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py from install of libstdc++-8.2.1-5.fc29.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-8.2.1-4.fc29.x86_64
```

I believe (think), that that `/usr/share/gcc-8/*` was part of my Apache Kafka Go Client installation and i really need it. Moreover, it was installed from source, so i have no tools to uninstall it in graceful way. Is there a way to fix that error?
I could try that `sudo yum install lib32stdc++6` mentioned in GitHub issue, but don't want to f*** my system as i am not sure what all this stuff means and as well that issue is quite old and it is strange that it is not fixed. Or it is.. just in other way. Sorry, i just switched from Windows to Linux few days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem and found the problem had been that I had multiple versions of one and the same libstdc++ installed.

1. Check if you have the same problem using `rpm -qa | grep libstdc++` should give you:

   ```
   libstdc++-8.2.1-4.fc29.x86_64
   libstdc++-8.2.1-5.fc29.x86_64
   ```
2. Then you can just remove the older package using `dnf remove libstdc++-8.2.1-4.fc29.x86_64`
3. Install the package you originally intended to: `dnf install libstdc++.i686`

Comment: Note that `dnf check` will show all duplicate packages and other possible problems like this.